# How do I display a JavaScript variable inside my HTML tags in JSP?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a function that gets the original String and slice it. How do it display the results in HTML?

```
function parsingfunction()
{
    var originalString = entity.getGenreSolr();
    var results = originalString.slice(1, -1);
    return results; 
}
</script>
<div class = "Option_Title_summary_summary">
<p>Genre List: ${parsingFunction}</p>
```

Comment: It's a valid question and should not have been downvoted before.

Answer (score 1):

Well the code you are using is incorrect because we can't update `HTML` with `JavaScript` variables this way, you have to update the `HTML` from `JavaScript` instead.

Your code will be like this:

```js
function parsingfunction() {
  /*var originalString = entity.getGenreSolr();
  var results = originalString.slice(1, -1);
  return results;*/
  return ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"].join(" -- ");
}

document.getElementById("genreList").textContent = "Genre List: " + parsingfunction();
```

```html
<div class="Option_Title_summary_summary">
  <p id="genreList"> </p>
```

I commented your old code to avoid Exceptions with `undefined` variables and I gave the `id="genreList"` to the paragraph so I can get it in the JS code.

**Note:**

There's another solution but it's not very recommended in JavaScript, by using `document.write()`:

```html
<script>
  function parsingfunction() {
    /*var originalString = entity.getGenreSolr();
    var results = originalString.slice(1, -1);
    return results;*/
    return ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"].join(" -- ");
  }
</script>
<div class="Option_Title_summary_summary">
  <script>
    document.write('<p> Genre List: ' + parsingfunction() + '</p>');
  </script>
```