# access javascript variable inside jsp html tag

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, variables

I have created variable in javascript, which I need to access inside if condition.

Below code is not working, I'm not able to access variable created in javascript, getting blank value.

```
<script>
var isComplete= "No";
function startup(){
 // some code which changing value for isComplete variable to "Yes";
}
</script>

<c:choose>
        <c:when test="${isComplete == 'No'}">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <td><a href="JavaScript:send('<c:out value="id"/>')">Send</a></td>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

I'm getting value of isComplete variable blank.
How can I access it?

Comment: A classic one: The key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server, when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser), and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

Comment: Please check code once, I'm performing operations in the startup function. there is no any case/condition of before or after response

Comment: There is simply **NO WAY** for the JSP to access Javascript variable within the same page. Your `startup()` function runs inside the browser, **after** the server has already **finished** processing the JSP. At the time of JSP processing, there is simply no `isComplete` JS variable yet, so you cannot access it.

Answer (score 0):

JSP code is executed on the server, whereas javascript code is executed in the browser, *after* the server has finished processing the JSP. Even the `startup()` in javascript is run in the browser some time after the JSP has finished execution.

If the purpose of accessing a javascript variable is to conditionally modify the html generated by the JSP, you can refactor your code to put the modifications in javascript as well, so it would run in the browser, and re-write the html as needed. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272549/how-do-i-display-a-javascript-variable-inside-my-html-tags-in-jsp) shows an example of how you might do it.